# Is "going on a technology retreat" ambiguous for you?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-case

I've using "being on a technology retreat" to mean that I will shun technology.

But my friend U says that this expression **cannot** signify retreating *from* technology; instead, it means retreating *to* a place full of latest-tech and gizmos. I agree that her reading is the dominant one but don't consider it the only available interpretation.

BONUS: Can more enlightened colleagues here please also explain what grammatical case "technology" adopts in the two readings — if two readings are, indeed, possible?

Edit 1: My question is can "X retreat" mean retreat from X in *any setting*. For instance, will the following be an **unacceptable** sentence for all native speakers:

> *Oh I hate all these iphones and social media. I'm going on a technology retreat this week*!

What about the following, eh?

> *Oh I hate all these iphones and social media. I'm going on a technological retreat this week*!

To emphasise the point, c.f. the following

- Oh I love the USSR, let's go on a Russian Retreat
- Damn, the latest Russian Retreat in the war has shocked many
- Russia's retreat from the world stage is due to China's rise

[BTW, this is why I **do** think that grammatical case is playing a role].

Comment: The issue is *retreat*, not tech. Maybe you're on a tech *fast*.

Comment: It doesn’t really have a “case”. It’s an [attributive noun](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct), functioning adjectivally.

Comment: You  are right that *X retreat*, so far as the syntax of the phrase is considered, can be argued to mean simply a retreat that has something to do with X, which is ambiguous between a retreat from X and a retreat from other things for the purpose of concentrating on X. You are also right that the latter meaning will almost always turn out to be the intended one; some very unusual context would be needed to indicate that the former meaning was intended. This site is, however, not well geared to questions to which the answer is simply 'Yeah, you are right'.

Comment: Do you want to be the person who says that a discriminating palate is good, so discrimination is good, damn the connotation?

Comment: Common use of "an X retreat" is to imply a gathering where people interested in "X" gather together to discuss X or study it somehow.

Comment: No ambiguity: In no way does *going on a technology retreat* mean retreating from technology.

Comment: I'm biased but @jsw29 seems to be the only one on the right track. I've edited the post to make my question clearer. Please have a look!

Answer (score 1):

Your meaning is not clear at all.

I looked at a list of nouns that commonly go before "retreat" (the 100 most common wordings in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for `NOUN retreat`) and none of them described an occasion where "NOUN" was avoided. The vast majority of the results were for formalized events (e.g. company retreats), and the noun was in one of the following categories:

- Location (beach retreat, mountain retreat)
- Duration/time (weekend retreat, autumn retreat)
- Organizers/participants (church retreat, leadership retreat)
- Purpose (yoga retreat, art retreat)

Searching Google I even found this "technology retreat" that falls into the last category: [AIMS Technology Retreat](https://www.aimsmddc.org/page/44). Even with the context given in your examples, this is along the lines of what I would assume you meant.

"Going on a break from technology" is a way to express what you want clearly.

Comment: Yes, it's sense 3 of [retreat, noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retreat) there which doesn't indicate leaving behind a particular thing.

Comment: This answer shows that it **happens to be the case** that *X retreat* is not used for a retreat from X, but that is compatible with arguing that **the syntax** of that phrase, considered in isolation from established usage, allows that meaning. Thus, if the OP were seeking practical advice, the response should indeed be 'Don't try to use the phrase that way, it would only cause confusion', but in so far as the OP is engaged in a purely theoretical argument, it can be said that 'Yes, theoretically, the phrase **could** be used that way; it just happens that it almost never is'.